# Is there a way to fetch a description of a certain release in a GitHub repository?

Tags: php, github, curl, github-api

I'm making a web application and I'm implementing a changelog system. My goal is, that whenever a changelog should be displayed (now, it doesn't matter how), my PHP script fetches the release info from the repository (specifically from URL https://github.com/MyUsername/MyRepositoryName/releases/tag/v7.3) and displays it in the changelog.

The problem is, that I feel like this might not be a long-term solution if GitHub changes it's HTML templates because I would probably find the element containing the information I need by its HTML id and/or classes.

Is there some kind of API that will allow me to fetch the description (and title of the release, if possible)?

Comment: Does it have to be from the given URL? Using the [GitHub Releases API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#releases) would make this a lot easier.

Comment: No, the URL would change dynamically. The name of the user and the repository would stay the same, but the version (or the tag name) would be changing.

I see that I can get information about the latest release by sending a GET request to `https://api.github.com/repos/MyName/MyRepositoryName/releases?per_page=1`, but is there a way to retrieve information about one specific release (by its tag name), without having to download the list of all of them and going through it and checking the "tag_name" for each of the entries?